# How can DWT be used in LSB substitution steganography

Tags: steganography, haar-wavelet, dwt, wavelet-transform

In steganography, the [least significant bit (LSB) substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Example_from_modern_practice) method embeds the secret bits in the place of bits from the cover medium, for example, image pixels. In some methods, the [Discrete Wavelet Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform) (DWT) of the image is taken and the secret bits are embedded in the DWT coefficients, after which the inverse trasform is used to reconstruct the stego image.

However, the DWT produces float coefficients and for the LSB substitution method integer values are required. Most papers I've read use the 2D Haar Wavelet, yet, they aren't clear on their methodology. I've seen the transform being defined in terms of low and high pass filters (float transforms), or taking the sum and difference of pair values, or the average and mean difference, etc.

More explicitly, either in the forward or the inverse transform (but not necessarily in both depending on the formulas used) eventually float numbers will appear. I can't have them for the coefficients because the substitution won't work and I can't have them for the reconstructed pixels because the image requires integer values for storage.

For example, let's consider a pair of pixels, `A` and `B` as a 1D array. The low frequency coefficient is defined by the sum, i.e., `s = A + B`, and the high frequency coefficient by the difference, i.e., `d = A - B`. We can then reconstruct the original pixels with `B = (s - d) / 2` and `A = s - B`. However, after any bit twiddling with the coefficients, `s - d` may not be even anymore and float values will emerge for the reconstructed pixels.

For the 2D case, the 1D transform is applied separately for the rows and the columns, so eventually a division by 4 will occur somewhere. This can result in values with float remainders .00, .25, .50 and .75. I've only come across [one paper](https://www.cyut.edu.tw/~ijase/2006/4-3(Microsoft%20Word%20-%20010-009-6).pdf) which addresses this issue. The rest are very vague in their methodology and I struggle to replicate them. Yet, the DWT has been widely implemented for image steganography.

My question is, since some of the literature I've read hasn't been enlightening, how can this be possible? How can one use a transform which introduces float values, yet the whole steganography method requires integers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution that has worked for me is using the Integer Wavelet Transform, which some also refer to as a [lifting scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting_scheme). For the Haar wavelet, I've seen it defined as:

```
s = floor((A + B) / 2)
d = A - B
```

And for inverse:

```
A = s + floor((d + 1) / 2)
B = s - floor(d / 2)
```

All the values throughout the whole process are integers. The reason it works is because the formulas contain information about both the even and odd parts of the pixels/coefficients, so there is no loss of information from rounding down. Even if one modifies the coefficients and then takes the inverse transform, the reconstructed pixels will still be integers.

Example implementation in Python:

```
import numpy as np

def _iwt(array):
    output = np.zeros_like(array)
    nx, ny = array.shape
    x = nx // 2
    for j in xrange(ny):
        output[0:x,j] = (array[0::2,j] + array[1::2,j])//2
        output[x:nx,j] = array[0::2,j] - array[1::2,j]
    return output

def _iiwt(array):
    output = np.zeros_like(array)
    nx, ny = array.shape
    x = nx // 2
    for j in xrange(ny):
        output[0::2,j] = array[0:x,j] + (array[x:nx,j] + 1)//2
        output[1::2,j] = output[0::2,j] - array[x:nx,j]
    return output

def iwt2(array):
    return _iwt(_iwt(array.astype(int)).T).T

def iiwt2(array):
    return _iiwt(_iiwt(array.astype(int).T).T)
```

Some languages already have built-in functions for this purpose. For example, Matlab uses [`lwt2()`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/lwt2.html) and [`ilwt2()`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/ilwt2.html) for 2D lifting-scheme wavelet transform.

```
els = {'p',[-0.125 0.125],0};
lshaarInt = liftwave('haar','int2int');
lsnewInt = addlift(lshaarInt,els);
[cAint,cHint,cVint,cDint] = lwt2(x,lsnewInt)    % x is your image
xRecInt = ilwt2(cAint,cHint,cVint,cDint,lsnewInt);
```

An article example where IWT was used for image steganography is [Raja, K.B. et. al (2008) Robust image adaptive steganography using integer wavelets.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sarvajith_M/publication/4346356_Robust_image_adaptive_steganography_using_integer_wavelets/links/0deec51b701be41d58000000.pdf)