# Embedding Text in Image DWT coefficients using Python

Tags: python, image, steganography, dwt, pywavelets

I'm trying to embed text data into the coefficients of DWT of an image/video frame to perform steganography. I have used PyWavelets to extract coefficients.

However, I'm struggling to understand how to manipulate the coefficients of DWT to embed the binary of the text.

**Can anyone guide me to perform what I'm trying to do ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: You can see all the wavelet options you have with `pywt.wavelist()`. I don't see an integer wavelet transform there, which is an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802827/how-can-dwt-be-used-in-lsb-substitution-steganography) I've struggled with in the past with steganography. But once you get integer coefficients, embedding your secret in them is the same as doing it in raw pixels with bit manipulation.

Comment: @Reti43 Thank you so much. I will check the post and try my best to figure it out . Again, thanks.

Comment: @Reti43 Is it okay to have your email and contact you via email ?